# Textarea aumentar conforme texto

Tags: javascript, textarea

//Porem  sem usar function e pegando mais de um TEXTAREA

```js
 function autoResize()
    {
        objTextArea = document.getElementById('txtTextArea');
        while (objTextArea.scrollHeight > objTextArea.offsetHeight)
        {
            objTextArea.rows += 1;
        }
    }
```

```html
<textarea id="txtTextArea" onkeydown="autoResize()"></textarea>
```

Comment: Sem usar `function`? explique isso

Comment: Pegando apenas pelo textarea ex: <textarea></<textarea> || sem usar o function dentro ... Não sei de deu para entender ?

Comment: Isso eu entendi, mas por que sem usar `function`?

Comment: por conta que aqui esse textarea é gerado automaticamente,ele vêem sem id e sem o onkeydown

Comment: E mesmo com o `function` não terá problema algum

Comment: Não tera problema não

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sem usar função, você pode colocar o JavaScript direto no elemento com `oninput`:

```html
<textarea oninput='if(this.scrollHeight > this.offsetHeight) this.rows += 1'></textarea>
```

Ou então criar um *listener* para todas as `textarea` que possuírem uma classe específica. No exemplo abaixo, só terá o efeito a `textarea` com a classe `.autoTxtArea`:

```js
var txtAreas = document.querySelectorAll('.autoTxtArea');
for(x=0;x<txtAreas.length;x++){
   txtAreas[x].addEventListener('input', function(){
        if(this.scrollHeight > this.offsetHeight) this.rows += 1;
   });
}
```

```html
<textarea placeholder="Com efeito" class="autoTxtArea" id="txtTextArea"></textarea>
<br />
<textarea placeholder="Sem efeito" id="txtTextArea"></textarea>
```

Comment: Vallleeew Era isso mesmo ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que o que você quer é fazer sem associar apenas um elemento como está dentro da função pegando o elemento pelo `id`.

Pode utilizar o `this` e alterar a função conforme abaixo:

```js
function autoResize(el){
  while (el.scrollHeight > el.offsetHeight){
    el.rows += 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<textarea onkeydown="autoResize(this)"></textarea>
<textarea onkeydown="autoResize(this)"></textarea>
```

Comment: Acho que ele quer sem usar `function`, só não entendi o porque ainda rs

Comment: sem o onkeydown="autoResize()", tudo direto pelo javascript sem colocar tag nenhuma no html não sei se deu para entender !

Comment: Entendi, seria a resposta do DvD então.

Answer (score -1):

Fiz uma atualização na function para resetar o imput caso apague todo texto

```
var txtAreas = document.querySelectorAll('.autoTxtArea');
for(x=0;x<txtAreas.length;x++){
    txtAreas[x].addEventListener('input', function(){
        if(this.value){
            if(this.scrollHeight > this.offsetHeight) 
                this.rows += 1;
        } else{
            this.rows = 10;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).